# Cloud SQL instances are not starting or restarting. It's stuck

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I was just trying to restart my Google Cloud SQL instances from command line. But it got stuck since 2 hours. I don't know why.

And from gcloud console I can't do any operation for my Cloud SQL instances. It's saying `ERROR: (gcloud.sql.instances.patch) HTTPError 409: The instance or operation is not in an appropriate state to handle the request.`

So is there anything I can perform a fresh restart? Even I couldn't get in touch with any technical support channel rather than here.

Comment: Hi Shaharia. I work on the Cloud SQL Team. Could you send an email to cloud-sql@google.com with your Google Cloud Project ID and Cloud SQL instance name for me to investigate?

Comment: @JuanEnriqueMuñozZolotoochin someone from your team already solved that.